Scroll position is not detect on React
I need to retrieve the scroll position to be able to remove the nav bar when the user scrolls down, currently the st variable
let st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

is always at 0 even when I scroll down.
Here the composant :

import "../App.css";
import { useEffect, useRef} from "react";

function NavBar({ sectionLists }){
    const Nav = useRef(null);
    const lastScrollTop = useRef(0);
    const HandleScrollInto = (name) => {
        sectionLists[name].current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const onScroll = () => {
            let st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

            console.log(st)
            if (st > lastScrollTop.current) {
                console.log('Scrolling DOWN');
            } else if (st < lastScrollTop.current) {
                console.log('Scrolling UP');
            }
            lastScrollTop.current = st;
        };

        window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll, true);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll, true);
        };
    }, []);


    return(
        <>
            <div className={"main-container"} id={"navId"} ref={Nav}>
            <div className={"nav-container"}>
                <div className={"name"}>
                    <h1 className={"hb"}>HB</h1>
                    <h4 className={"web"}>Web developer<br/>Fullstack</h4>
                </div>

                <h2 className={"hamza"} onClick={() => HandleScrollInto('Bio')}>Hamza Benkejjane</h2>

                <div className={"ul-list"}>
                    <ul>
                        <li onClick={() => HandleScrollInto('Home')}>HOME</li>
                        <li onClick={() => HandleScrollInto('Project')} >PROJECT</li>
                        <li onClick={() => HandleScrollInto('Inspiration')} >INSPIRATIONS</li>
                        <li onClick={() => HandleScrollInto('Contact')}>CONTACT</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default NavBar;

the logic is when I call the onScroll function in an event to scroll on the page, the event works but it's really the scroll position that stays at 0 all the time

let st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

Above expression gives boolean result because you applied || operator. You should use any one (either window.pageYOffset or document.documentElement.scrollTop) to get position from top. I'd recommend you to use window.pageYOffset since it represents the scroll position relative to the top of the viewport and it is better cross-browser supporting.

i put :             let st =  window.pageYOffset;
but when i console.log st and i scroll, the value is always 0

The possible reason might be because you put your event handler in the Nav container (which initially stays intact on scrolling). Try putting event handler on the parent components.

window.addEventListener('scroll', ()=>onScroll(), true); 
